# Joomla 3.6 - 3.7 - white page in backend - Fatal error login.php

Tags: authentication, joomla, fatal-error

I have an error on backend in Joomla website. When I insert user and password I can see this errors:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /web/htdocs/www.namesite.it/home/libraries/joomla/input/input.php on line 323
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in /web/htdocs/www.namesite.it/home/administrator/components/com_login/models/login.php on line 33

If I deactivate a `com_login` I can see regular structure but I can enter on backend...

This is the file `administrator/components/com_login/models/login.php`

```
<?php
/**
 * @package     Joomla.Administrator
 * @subpackage  com_login
 *
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2005 - 2016 Open Source Matters, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 */

defined('_JEXEC') or die;

/**
 * Login Model
 *
 * @since  1.5
 */
class LoginModelLogin extends JModelLegacy
{
    /**
     * Method to auto-populate the model state.
     *
     * Note. Calling getState in this method will result in recursion.
     *
     * @return  void
     *
     * @since   1.6
     */
    protected function populateState()
    {
        $input = JFactory::getApplication()->input->getInputForRequestMethod();

        $credentials = array(
            'username'  => $input->get('username', '', 'USERNAME'),
            'password'  => $input->get('passwd', '', 'RAW'),
            'secretkey' => $input->get('secretkey', '', 'RAW'),
        );
        $this->setState('credentials', $credentials);

        // Check for return URL from the request first.
        if ($return = $input->get('return', '', 'BASE64'))
        {
            $return = base64_decode($return);

            if (!JUri::isInternal($return))
            {
                $return = '';
            }
        }

        // Set the return URL if empty.
        if (empty($return))
        {
            $return = 'index.php';
        }

        $this->setState('return', $return);
    }

    /**
     * Get the administrator login module by name (real, eg 'login' or folder, eg 'mod_login').
     *
     * @param   string  $name   The name of the module.
     * @param   string  $title  The title of the module, optional.
     *
     * @return  object  The Module object.
     *
     * @since   11.1
     */
    public static function getLoginModule($name = 'mod_login', $title = null)
    {
        $result = null;
        $modules = self::_load($name);
        $total = count($modules);

        for ($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++)
        {
            // Match the title if we're looking for a specific instance of the module.
            if (!$title || $modules[$i]->title == $title)
            {
                $result = $modules[$i];
                break;
            }
        }

        // If we didn't find it, and the name is mod_something, create a dummy object.
        if (is_null($result) && substr($name, 0, 4) == 'mod_')
        {
            $result = new stdClass;
            $result->id = 0;
            $result->title = '';
            $result->module = $name;
            $result->position = '';
            $result->content = '';
            $result->showtitle = 0;
            $result->control = '';
            $result->params = '';
            $result->user = 0;
        }

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Load login modules.
     *
     * Note that we load regardless of state or access level since access
     * for public is the only thing that makes sense since users are not logged in
     * and the module lets them log in.
     * This is put in as a failsafe to avoid super user lock out caused by an unpublished
     * login module or by a module set to have a viewing access level that is not Public.
     *
     * @param   string  $module  The name of the module.
     *
     * @return  array
     *
     * @since   11.1
     */
    protected static function _load($module)
    {
        static $clean;

        if (isset($clean))
        {
            return $clean;
        }

        $app = JFactory::getApplication();
        $lang = JFactory::getLanguage()->getTag();
        $clientId = (int) $app->getClientId();

        $cache = JFactory::getCache('com_modules', '');
        $cacheid = md5(serialize(array($clientId, $lang)));
        $loginmodule = array();

        if (!($clean = $cache->get($cacheid)))
        {
            $db = JFactory::getDbo();

            $query = $db->getQuery(true)
                ->select('m.id, m.title, m.module, m.position, m.showtitle, m.params')
                ->from('#__modules AS m')
                ->where('m.module =' . $db->quote($module) . ' AND m.client_id = 1')
                ->join('LEFT', '#__extensions AS e ON e.element = m.module AND e.client_id = m.client_id')
                ->where('e.enabled = 1');

            // Filter by language.
            if ($app->isSite() && $app->getLanguageFilter())
            {
                $query->where('m.language IN (' . $db->quote($lang) . ',' . $db->quote('*') . ')');
            }

            $query->order('m.position, m.ordering');

            // Set the query.
            $db->setQuery($query);

            try
            {
                $modules = $db->loadObjectList();
            }
            catch (RuntimeException $e)
            {
                JError::raiseWarning(500, JText::sprintf('JLIB_APPLICATION_ERROR_MODULE_LOAD', $e->getMessage()));

                return $loginmodule;
            }

            // Return to simple indexing that matches the query order.
            $loginmodule = $modules;

            $cache->store($loginmodule, $cacheid);
        }

        return $loginmodule;
    }
}
```

Can I solve it? Thanks

Comment: I'm facing same problem on my Joomla! 3.7.5 version, I tried to compare your file with version 3.7.5 version and are really different. All parameters on login are sent correctly. Seems strange to me since of what I know nothing special was done on the website.

Comment: When are you getting the white page?  The question is confusing.  Usually white pages are due to bad plugins.

Comment: I didn't doing any update and website came back regular.

Answer (score 1):

We have found the cause of the issues.
Patchman released patches for some joomla files recently which are breaking joomla sites when applied.

If you (or your provider) is using Patchman, rolling back the patches should fix it.